# treading a path

Tags: phrasal-verbs

"He trod a path"
This sentence seems to have two different meanings:
1. He walked (through the grass, for example) and his heavy steps shaped a path.
2. He walked along a path.
I would like to know if it is possible to add a preposition after "trod" to remove the ambiguity. 
For example, is it correct to write: "he trod upon a path" or "he trod along a path".
Thank you for your advice.

Comment: *Trod*, no `e`.

Comment: @DanBron: Or possibly *strode* (which might explain the confusion).

Comment: @Dan: Trode was used before we were born. I think the question came from the Medieval Ages.

Comment: @TimLymington Hmm, I don't know if *striding* a path through the savannah would connote "pushing down the grass and creating a visible path".

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. I should have written "trod"!

Comment: @Thalie It is not something to say sorry about. No worry. People make a mistake and learn from it. You won't be able to forget this word for the rest of your life.

Comment: @Rathony . Thanks for your sense of humour! I will certainly remember the verb and its past form but I still don't know how to use it in a full sentence...

Comment: @Thalie I posted an answer below. Hope you like it.

Comment: Even without the *e* the usage is something musty, and most likely to be *(a)* metaphorical and *(b)* encountered in a eulogy.

Comment: You should correct the spelling, as the OP it's your question, and you can improve your post when you see fit. It seems silly to me to leave a typo/spelling mistake after it's been pointed out *and* acknowledged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always recommend looking up to a dictionary when you encounter this kind of "word usage issue".

According to Merriam-Webster,

tread is **a transitive verb** when you shape a path. Therefore, you should not use a preposition.

Also, when you use "tread" to mean "walk along", it is **also a transitive verb**. So, you should not use a preposition.

Hope it helps.

Comment: .Thank you very much for your answer that I have just read.

Comment: My pleasure. Nobody can beat a dictionary.

Comment: But that means that "trod a path" can mean either that he _created_ a path, or simply _followed_ it.  Awkward.  The only way I can think of to avoid this ambiguity is to use **forged** a path to mean he created it.

Comment: @Brian, I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

Transitive verbs have intransitive uses.  That is, even when a verb may take an object, it needn't necessarily have to take one.  Thus it is with "tread."  The Ngram viewer finds numerous instances of the intransitive use of this verb, and I present one below from *[Along the Road: A Parabolic Appalachian Journey](https://books.google.com/books?id=KUscj54kn8AC&pg=PA93&dq=%22trod%20along%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAGoVChMIs6T706mVyAIVSGk-Ch0WdAJ7#v=onepage&q=%22trod%20along%22&f=false)* by J. T. Elder:

> Paul's pulse quickened as he considered this possibility. He had
>   sought the career path he had long **trod** along for one primary
>   reason: security!

Comment: "Paul's pulse" is a somewhat unhappy alliteration, and then "he had long trod along". Ugly sentences.

Comment: @Mari-LouA It's better than the original:  "Paul's pulse pounded as he pondered the possibility."

Comment: Give me the original any day! :)